# How to create a new row in a SQLite table with the ID column only?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in an SQLite database on Android that only contains a column with the row ID. This table is used to link datasets in different tables. When I try to insert a new row in the table it throws this exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO journeyDetailsTable(null)
>   VALUES (NULL)

My table is created like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_JOURNEY_DETAIL = "create table " +
        TABLE_NAME + " (" + ID_COLUMN + " integer primary key autoincrement);";
```

And I am trying to insert a new row like this:

```
parentID = db.insert(ANOTHER_TABLE, null, new ContentValues());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to link tables, you shoud have **2 id columns**. To link table A and table B (for instance), you should have table C containing id_A and id_B.

Comment: Right now my setup is like this: Table A is the main table, the one that links them all together by the row id. 3 other tables has foreign keys to the row id of the main table. They all has a one-to-many relationship between the main table and the other tables. Meaning that one row id of the main table can Refer to many rows in the other tables.

Comment: So, is Table A **really needed**? I think you can get rid of it.

Comment: Maybe not. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [SQLiteDatabase.insert(String, String, ContentValues)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) clearly state that SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. This means that if you do not specify any values, you need to specify a column name in which to insert the NULL into. You should be fine with `db.insert(ANOTHER_TABLE, ID_COLUMN, new ContentValues())` to accomplish that.

Regardless, you should probably re-think your database structure as having tables set up like this does not seem effective, maintainable and overseeable, especially in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass ID_COLUMN as column name in your insert, null isn't a column, but passing null to id will let ID be auto-incremented:

```
INSERT INTO journeyDetailsTable(ID_COLUMN) VALUES (NULL)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cd349/1)